# Some functions $\phi:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb C$ that satisfy $\phi(x)\bar\phi(y)=\phi(x-y)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let us consider the function $\phi(x)$, $\phi:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb C$ and indicate with $\bar \phi$ the conjugate of $\phi$. We consider the property: $$\phi(x)\overline{\phi(y)}=\phi(x-y)$$
The exponential function $e^{ix}$ ($x\in\mathbb R$), for example, satisfies this property. Is it the only function that satisfies this property? Do you know the other examples on this property?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The zero function? The constant $1$ function?

Comment: It is an example, thank you :)

Comment: Observation: Such a function must satisfy $\phi (x)= \bar\phi (-x)$. Indeed:  $\phi (x)\bar\phi(y)=\phi(x-y)$ implies $\bar\phi (x)\phi(y)=\bar\phi(x-y)$ and therefore, since $\bar\phi (x)\phi(y)=\phi(y-x)$, we have $\bar\phi(x-y)=\phi(y-x)$. Maybe this is useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume $\overline{\phi(0)}\ne 0$, then $$\phi(0)=|\phi(0)|^2$$ so $\phi(0)>0$ therefore $\phi(0)=1$. From this we have $\phi(-x)=\overline{\phi(x)}$. As such, $1=\phi(x-x)=|\phi(x)|^2$, so really

> $$\phi:\Bbb R\to S^1$$

and $\phi$ is a [homomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_homomorphism) by the given property. If you are willing to assume continuity, we know the continuous homomorphisms (i.e. [group characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_group)) from $\Bbb R\to S^1$ are just the maps

$$\{x\mapsto e^{i\alpha x}:\alpha\in\Bbb R\}\qquad (*)$$

So this is a complete characterization. In particular, since I added the little $\alpha$ in there, you have yourself uncountably infinitely many more examples!

---

You only asked about examples, but in case you're interested in how the classification of $(*)$ goes, it's not terribly hard if you know a little about basic topology (local compactness mostly) and it is presented very well in Tate's thesis or André Weil's *Basic Number Theory* (among other places).

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your answer. But who is $S^1$?

Comment: $S^1$ is the unit circle of complex numbers of absolute value 1.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $\phi$ is not the zero function, we can show that if a function satisfies your functional equation then $\phi(0)=1$. This follows since $$\phi(x) = \phi(x+0) = \phi(x)\overline{\phi(0)}.$$

If we further assume that the function is differentiable at zero, then we can see that:

$$\phi'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\phi(x+h)-\phi(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\phi(x)(\overline{\phi(-h)} - 1)}{h} = \phi(x) \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\phi(h)-1}{h} = \phi(x) \phi'(0).$$

Here we used $\overline{\phi(-h)}=\phi(h)$ as was outlined in the comments. Thus $\phi$ satisfies the equation $\phi' = C\phi$ where $C = \phi'(0)$, and so we have $\phi = e^{C x}$ for some $C$.

To determine $C$, we re-examine the funcitonal equation. $e^{Cx}e^{\overline{C}y} = e^{C(x-y)}.$

Hence $Cx + \bar C y = C(x-y) + 2\pi\cdot k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. This tells us that $\bar C y= - Cy + 2\pi \cdot k$. Further $\bar C + C = 2\pi \frac{k}y$. However, since $y$ can change, $k$ must be $0$. Thus $\bar C + C = 0$ and this means $C$ is imaginary.

Comment: In case you're interested, you can get the differentiability just from assuming continuity if you are willing to do a bit of legwork and want to prove things under milder hypotheses.